# Calling subclass constructor corresponding to enum value

Tags: java, enums

I have a method which creates a new EntityItem:

```
    public void processEntityItem(int[] a){
        float x = Float.intBitsToFloat(a[4]);
        float y = Float.intBitsToFloat(a[5]);
        main.entitys.add(new EntityItem(EntityType.values()[a[2]], a[3], x, y, main.mr.getHieght(x, y), Float.intBitsToFloat(a[6]), a[7]));
    }
```

Each of my EntityItems have an enum (EntityType) value asigned to them and the first argument in the constructor is that enum value. I also have some subclasses of EntityItem which i would like to create either from this method or from the constructor of EntityItem which is this:

```
    public EntityItem(EntityType type, int ID, float xCoord, float yCoord, float zCoord, float rotation, int mapID) {
        super(type, ID, xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, rotation, mapID);
    }
```

An example of a subclass of EntityItem constructor:

```
    public EntityArrow(int ID, float x, float y, float z, float rotation,  int mapID){
        super(EntityType.ARROW, ID, x, y, z, rotation, mapID);
        createModel();
    }
```

The only way i can think of to do this is to switch through all of the values of the enum type and call the constructor that corresponds to each value. Is there a different way to check if there is a subclass corresponding to the enum value passed and if so call that subclass constructor that doesnt require me to write out every enum value?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I can't understand what you want to do. what does "a subclass corresponding to the enum value" mean? passed to what? How could you call the constructor of an object that is passed as argument? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have an enum value which represents either an instance of EntityItem or a subclass of it. If it represents a subclass then i would like to create an instance of that subclass instead of an instance of Entityitem as my method processEntityItem currently does. Otherwise I create an instance of EntityItem.

Comment: Are the constructor arguments always the same?

Comment: Yes, the arguments are always the same. the subclassess with only one possible enum value, for example EntityArrow above, omit the enum value, but I could allow them to take it if necessary.

Comment: That sounds like a candidate for a factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constructor arguments are always the same, the enum itself could act as the factory instead of your controlling code. For example:

```
public enum EntityType {

    ARROW {
        @Override
        public EntityItem makeEntity(
                int id,
                float x,
                float y,
                float z,
                float rotation,
                int mapId
        ) {
            // uses subclass
            return new EntityArrow(id, x, y, z, rotation, mapId);
        }
    },
    CIRCLE {
        @Override
        public EntityItem makeEntity(
                int id,
                float x,
                float y,
                float z,
                float rotation,
                int mapId
        ) {
            // uses base class
            return new EntityItem(this, id, x, y, z, rotation, mapId);
        }
    };

    public abstract EntityItem makeEntity(
            int id,
            float x,
            float y,
            float z,
            float rotation,
            int mapId
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great after modifying it a bit to acount for my other Entitys which are not EntityItems.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static factory method in your super class, that contains a switch statement, or create a polymorphic factory method in your enum type.